# How can I print an object in cy.log()?

Tags: javascript, json, object, cypress

**Use case**

This is a Cypress E2E test coded with JS and I'm trying to compare pre-production and production sitemap URL contents in order to find the differences. I have two data sets (fixture) one for production and the other for test env.

Code snippet:

```
let compareUrlsBetween = (prodSitemapUrls, testEnvSitemapUrls) => {
                                    const pathFirstEnv = new Set(JSON.parse(prodSitemapUrls).map(url => (new URL(url)).pathname))
                                    const pathSecondEnv = new Set(JSON.parse(testEnvSitemapUrls).map(url => (new URL(url)).pathname))
                                    const diff = new Set(pathFirstEnv);
                                    for (const path of pathSecondEnv) {
                                        diff.delete(path);
                                    }
                                    return diff
                                }

                                // Check for differences
                                if (compareUrlsBetween.length > 0) {
                                    let titi = typeof(compareUrlsBetween(prodSitemapUrls, testEnvSitemapUrls))
                                    console.log(titi)
                                    
                                    cy.log('text : ' , compareUrlsBetween (prodSitemapUrls, testEnvSitemapUrls))   // Returns null
                                    
                                    //console.log(compareUrlsBetween(prodSitemapUrls, testEnvSitemapUrls))
                                    //console.log('Production and test env sitemap urls are not ISO, ' + 'Here are the differences : ' , compareUrlsBetween (prodSitemapUrls, testEnvSitemapUrls))
                                    //throw new Error()
                                } else {
                                    expect(prodSitemapUrls).to.eq(testEnvSitemapUrls)
                                }
```

**Test goal & the problem**

Test goal is to fail the test in cas of diff between these two fixtures (.xml), throw a new error and show the diff as normal log (cy.log()). I've already tried multiple solutions like `JSON.stringify()`, data type conversion etc. but none of them solved my case.

Log I observe at this moment : `logtext : , {}`

**PS**: the other type of logs like console.log() or console.table() are working perfectly fine

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `{}` is clearly not `null`

Comment: Indeed @KonradLinkowski , it's not but I can't show the data as a normal log (cy.log), This is what I see but as console version : Set(2) {'/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_product_1.xml', '/flux/sitemaps/sitemap_product_2.xml'}

Comment: What about `cy.log('text : ' , [...compareUrlsBetween (prodSitemapUrls, testEnvSitemapUrls)])`?

Comment: Thank you very much @KonradLinkowski, it works like a charm, already tried this solution but I've forgotten to put ... before my function name :)

Answer (score 5):

### Solution

Convert the set into an array

```
cy.log('text : ' , [...compareUrlsBetween (prodSitemapUrls, testEnvSitemapUrls)])
```

### Why?

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems like `cy.log` uses `JSON.stringify` underneath which causes sets to be converted to `{}`

Comment: Thank you @KonradLinkowski for the explanation, I think you've said it right, just saw a similaire problematic in another disscution with the same reasoning. In my case I was trying to double JSON.stringify an object and that's why an empty string was returned which is an error, was good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Although the dev console of Cypress will not keep any indentation you could configure, it gives you a full output.

E.g.: `cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body))`

Comment: Thanks, this little trick was really helpful!!